# Automated Installation of LAMP Stack Using Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, installation, lamp

How to automate the installation of LAMP Stack? As we have to install several packages one by one and then configure them. Again we have to separately install some GUI tool like phpMyAdmin or MySQL-Workbench to access MySQL databases. Is it possible to make this full installation completely automated? Using shell script or something else?

Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have prepared the following shell script to make this installation fully automated.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ******************************************
# Program: LAMP Stack Installation Script
# Developer: Pratik Patil
# Date: 10-04-2015
# Last Updated: 11-01-2016
# ******************************************

if [ "`lsb_release -is`" == "Ubuntu" ] || [ "`lsb_release -is`" == "Debian" ]
then
    sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-workbench libmysqld-dev;
    sudo apt-get -y install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt phpmyadmin;
    sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/;
    sudo printf "<?php\nphpinfo();\n?>" > /var/www/html/info.php;
    sudo service apache2 restart;

elif [ "`lsb_release -is`" == "CentOS" ] || [ "`lsb_release -is`" == "RedHat" ]
then
    sudo yum -y install httpd mysql-server mysql-devel php php-mysql php-fpm;
    sudo yum -y install epel-release phpmyadmin rpm-build redhat-rpm-config;
    sudo yum -y install mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm proj;
    sudo yum -y install tinyxml libzip mysql-workbench-community;
    sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/;
    sudo printf "<?php\nphpinfo();\n?>" > /var/www/html/info.php;
    sudo service mysqld restart;
    sudo service httpd restart;
    sudo chkconfig httpd on;
    sudo chkconfig mysqld on;

else
    echo "Unsupported Operating System";
fi
```

Open Following  URL in browser to verify the installation of Apache Server:

```
http://localhost
```

Open Following  URL in browser to verify the installation of PHP:

```
http://localhost/info.php
```

Comment: Whatever your problem, **`chmod 777` is wrong and insecure**.  You should understand the permissions model, and change the permissions to something sane like 755.  You **do not want** to grant everyone unrestricted write access to your files.  Doing so significantly increases the attack surface if somebody manages to break into your box.

Answer (score 0):

This process is distribution/package manager dependent, but yes, it is entirely possible. You can even enable `ssl/https` capability and generate your server keys, certificate, and signing request key all with a single keystroke. You break it down into tasks and add script capability for each. Key generation will require `ssh-keygen`. I have older versions of similar scripts for both openSuSE and Archlinux. If you get stuck, I'm happy to take a look and share the approach I took years ago.

In your script above, I would limit the permissions on `/var/www` to `0755`, no need to give `world` write to those directories -- ever. Additionally, instead of an extended `if .. elif ... elif ... fi` setup for identifying the distribution, A case statement can help you organize a bit more:

```
case "lsb_release" in 

    Ubuntu  )
        ... ;;
    Debian  )
        ... ;;
    Centos  )
        ... ;;
esac
```